# 1 How to insert a Date Picker to a cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to add a date piker or calendar to a cell but the Developer tab doesn't have the option to add one, i count find any information on what to do if is not on the developer tab.

Comment: Date piker? Are you asking for today's date? If you want today's date just type =today()

Comment: i want a calendar to open when i click on the cell so i can pick the date i need.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to turn on the developer tab, which you said you have.

Next, go to insert (subsection is 'controls')

Then, under ActiveX controls, go to more controls.

Last, 'select Microsoft Date and Time Picker'.

When you want to turn on the calendar, you will need to turn off design mode, found under the developer tab, and controls section.

I used this article to guide me.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/10/12/insert-calendar-excel-datepicker-template/

Comment: thanks for your replay, the problem I'm running in to is that under more controls I don't have the option to select Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0 (SP6). and I don't know how to add it.

Comment: @Badbuny that is because it's not available in newer Office versions.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not support Excel Date Picker in 64-bit. It also needs a macro-enabled workbook. However, it is still possible if you are using 32-bit Excel. There are other third-party options, some of which are free. You don’t even need to write any code to use them. The following post will examine three excellent ways to set up the Excel date picker.

https://kudutek.com/excel/excel-date-picker/

This calendar date-picker is from a paid add-in that gives you a resizeable calendar date-picker with up to a 12-month view. It also shows the corresponding date on the calendar when you select a cell with a date value.

https://kudutek.com/xlnavigator/features/dates/date-picker-calendar/